# Can I say "You might know it yet"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I wonder if I could say "You might know it yet" instead of saying "You might haven't known it". I just to make sure he/she knows it. Can anyone tell me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would say "You might already know" when you are telling someone a fact and want to acknowledge that they may already be aware of it.

You can't say "You might haven't known it". You would say "You might not know it" or "You might not have known it". (and "might not" can be shortened to "mightn't" in both cases)

"You might know it yet" *could* be used in a poetic/archaic sense to indicate that something may happen in the future.

"I have not known the sorrow of losing a brother"

"You might know it yet"

But this is not colloquial English.

Answer (score 0):

'You might know it yet' would be the same as 'You might know it still' when used for something you are about to reveal or something is about to happen.
Note that this is mostly used in everyday exchange and is not the text-book okay representation, however it is used widely to create the poetic/ dramatic flair in the dialogues.

Comment: "You might know it yet" is not idiomatic in American or British English. It may be acceptable in Indian English, but an American or British speaker would always choose "You might already know it" over this.

Comment: This use of "yet" seems old-fashioned to me. Although [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet) has "is yet a new country" with the meaning "continuously up to the present or a specified time", not marked as outdated. So maybe it's more literary than archaic.